# Creating template types without new/delete

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, variadic-templates

I have a C++ Object class like this:

```cpp
class Component {};

template <typename T>
concept component = std::is_base_of_v<Component, T>;

class Object
{
  std::map<std::type_index, Component*> components;

public:
  template<component T>
  T* add()
  {
    if(components.find(typeid(T)) == components.cend())
    {
      T* value{new T{}};
      components[typeid(T)] = static_cast<Component*>(value);
    }
  }

  template<component T, typename... Args>
  T* add(Args &&... args)
  {
    if(components.find(typeid(T)) == components.cend())
    {
      T* value{new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}};
      components[typeid(T)] = static_cast<Component*>(value);
    }
  }
};
```

`Component`s that are added to `class Object` are `delete`d on another function that is not related to my question. AFAIK doing a lot of `new`/`delete` calls (heap allocations) hurt performance and supposedly there should be like 20/30 (or even more) `Objects`s with 3-10 `Object::add` on each one. I thought that I could just call `T`-s constructor without `new`, then to `static_cast<Component*>(&value)`, but the Component added on the map is "invalid", meaning all T's members (ex. on a class with some `int` members, they are all equal to `0` instead of some custom value passed on its constructor). I am aware that `value` goes out of scope and the pointer on the `map` becomes a dangling one, but I can't find a way to instantiate `T` objects without calling `new` or without declaring them as `static`. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: If I declare `value` as `static`, everything works as expected, so I guess its a lifetime issue related to `value`.

Comment: Can you explain the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am trying to remove those `new`/`delete` calls, but as @Olaf Dietsche mentioned, if I write the snippet he shared, `value` variable would go out of scope and `components` map would contain dangling pointers. If I declare `value` as `static`, it would have the programs lifetime and problem solved, but I want to find a cheaper way of creating `T`s and storing them on `components` map (other than using `new`/`static`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you think of this as the alternative way of creating your objects

```
T value{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
components[typeid(T)] = static_cast<Component*>(&value);
```

This creates a local variable on the stack. Doing the assignment then, stores a pointer to a local variable in the `map`.

When you leave method `add()`, the local object will be destroyed, and you have a dangling pointer in the map. This, in turn, will bite you eventually.

---

As long as you want to store pointers, there's no way around new and delete. You can mitigate this a bit with some sort of [memory pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool).

If you may also store objects instead of pointers in the map, you could create the components in place with [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace). When you do this, you must also remove the call to `delete` and clean up the objects some other way.

Comment: I see. The code works fine if I add `static` when constructing `value` (sth like:
```c++
static T value{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
```
so that's definitely a lifetime issue. I updated the question info, but I still have to find sth cheaper than some `std::map`s of `static` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to avoid heap allocations before you've proven that they indeed hurt your programs' performance is not a good approach in my opinion. If that was the case, you should probably get rid of `std::map` in your code as well. That being said, if you really want to have no `new`/`delete` calls there, it can be done, but requires explicit enumeration of the `Component` types. Something like this could be what you are looking for:

```
#include <array>
#include <variant>

// Note that components no longer have to implement any specific interface, which might actually be useful.
struct Component1 {};
struct Component2 {};

// Component now is a variant enumerating all known component types.
using Component = std::variant<std::monostate, Component1, Component2>;

struct Object {
  // Now there is no need for std::map, as we can use variant size 
  // and indexes to create and access a std::array, which avoids more
  // dynamic allocations.
  std::array<Component, std::variant_size_v<Component> - 1> components;

  bool add (Component component) {
      // components elements hold std::monostate by default, and holding std::monostate
      // is indicated by returning index() == 0.
      if (component.index() > 0 && components[component.index() - 1].index() == 0) {
          components[component.index() - 1] = std::move(component);
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
};
```

`Component` enumerates all known component types, this allows to avoid dynamic allocation in `Object`, but can increase memory usage, as the memory used for single `Object` is roughly `number_of_component_types * size_of_largest_component`.

Comment: I need the Component-deriven structs to hold specific data (ex. an AnimationComponent class will hold animation-related data).  The base `Component` class was just used to have a common point for all Components so that I could write a `concept ` to use in `add`. I know that I am maybe crossing the line with my "requirements", but `Component`-derived classes are supposed to be written from any file that `#include`s "Object.h" (the file where `class Component` is declared). This means that `using Component` should be modified by anybody, which is error-prone on my case.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers made clear what the problem is I want to make a proposition how you could get around this in its entirety.

You know at compile time what possible types will be in the map at mosz, since you know which instantation of the `add` template where used. Hence you can get rid of the map and do all in a compile time.

```
template<component... Comps>
struct object{
    std::tuple<std::optional<Comps>...> components;

    template<component comp, class ... args>
    void add(Args... &&args) {
        std::get<std::optional<comp>>(components).emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

Of course this forces you to collect all the possible objects when you create the object, but this not more info you have to have just more impractical.

You could add the following overload for `add` to make the errors easier to read

```
template<component T>
void add(...) {
    static_assert(false, "Please add T to the componentlist of this object");
}
```

Comment: As a mater of fact, I don't know at compile time what exact types the map will hold, but I know that these types are all derived from an empty `Component` class, hence I wrote `template<component T>` rather than `template<class T>`. The idea is that me or any "user" of the code can derive their own `component` types from `class Component`. Besides that, the solution is nice thought and I think that `std::optional` can be removed easily from the code without any side effects.

Comment: You can only remove the `optional` if you can construct all classes when you construct the object (e.g. if everything is default constructible). But the optional is no problem, it does not do any heap allocations but is basically just enough space for the object and a flag if its there or not. And if you do not know which components can be there (not will, but can be), then you have a problem with your above code. Since for every component you have, you need to instantiate the `add` template with the right type as T.